# Flutter Build Issue: Build APK Fails for flutter App

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, gradle, build

C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat – no-color build apk
Waiting for another flutter command to release the startup lock...
You are building a fat APK that includes binaries for android-arm, android-ARM64, android-x64.
If you are deploying the app to the Play Store, it's recommended to use app bundles or split the APK to reduce the APK size.
To generate an app bundle, run:
flutter build appbundle – target-platform android-arm, android-ARM64, android-x64
Learn more on: https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle
To split the APKs per ABI, run:
flutter build apk – target-platform android-arm, android-ARM64, android-x64 – split-per-abi
Learn more on:  https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits#configure-abi-split
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app: mergeReleaseResources'.

> Multiple task action failures occurred:
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> > Android resource compilation failed
> C:\Users\mysel\AndroidStudioProjects\Chatting-app-with-firebase\android\app\src\main\res\mipmap-hdpi\ic_launcher.png: AAPT: error: failed to read PNG signature: file does not start with PNG signature.

```
    C:\Users\mysel\AndroidStudioProjects\Chatting-app-with-firebase\android\app\src\main\res\mipmap-hdpi\ic_launcher.png: AAPT: error: file failed to compile.
```

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> > Android resource compilation failed
> C:\Users\mysel\AndroidStudioProjects\Chatting-app-with-Firebase\Android\app\src\main\res\mipmap-xxhdpi\ic_launcher.png: AAPT: error: failed to read PNG signature: file does not start with PNG signature.

```
    C:\Users\mysel\AndroidStudioProjects\Chatting-app-with-firebase\android\app\src\main\res\mipmap-xxhdpi\ic_launcher.png: AAPT: error: file failed to compile.
```

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> > Android resource compilation failed

```
    C:\Users\mysel\AndroidStudioProjects\Chatting-app-with-firebase\android\app\src\main\res\mipmap-xxxhdpi\ic_launcher.png: AAPT: error: failed to read PNG signature: file does not start with PNG signature.

    C:\Users\mysel\AndroidStudioProjects\Chatting-app-with-firebase\android\app\src\main\res\mipmap-xxxhdpi\ic_launcher.png: AAPT: error: file failed to compile.
```

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> > Android resource compilation failed
> C:\Users\mysel\AndroidStudioProjects\Chatting-app-with-Firebase\Android\app\src\main\res\mipmap-mdpi\ic_launcher.png: AAPT: error: failed to read PNG signature: file does not start with PNG signature.

```
    C:\Users\mysel\AndroidStudioProjects\Chatting-app-with-firebase\android\app\src\main\res\mipmap-mdpi\ic_launcher.png: AAPT: error: file failed to compile.
```

- Try:
  Run with – stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with – info or – debug option to get more log output. Run with – scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 16s

Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...    80.3s
The built failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin. The tool is about to try using Jetfier to solve the incompatibility.
✏️  Creating `android\settings_aar.gradle`...
[!] Flutter tried to create the file `android\settings_aar.gradle`, but failed.
To manually update `settings.gradle`, follow these steps:

1. Copy `settings.gradle` as `settings_aar.gradle`
2. Remove the following code from `settings_aar.gradle`:

   ```
    def localPropertiesFile = new File(rootProject.projectDir, "local.properties")
    def properties = new Properties()

    assert localPropertiesFile.exists()
    localPropertiesFile.withReader("UTF-8") { reader -> properties.load(reader) }

    def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
    assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
    apply from: "$flutterSdkPath/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/app_plugin_loader.gradle"
   ```

Please create the file and run this command again.
Process finished with exit code 1

Tried changing daemon in build.properties file, tried Invalidate cache/restart but nothing seems to work

Comment: Try changing your ic_launcher to an actual PNG image. Don't change the extension of a JPEG file

Comment: I tried that, it didn't work. I also created settings_aar.gradle file, that too didn't work